# How to map enum to it's own property with MapStruct?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, mapstruct

I have a enum:

```
public enum TagClassEnum {
    COMMON(0, "common");

    Integer code;
    String desc;
}
```

and two bean:

```
class TagDTO {
    private TagClassEnum tagClass;
}

class TagPO {
    private Integer tagClass; // this refers TagClassEnum's code
}
```

Now I want to map the enum to code with MapStruct:

```
@Mappings({@Mapping(source = ???, target = ???)})
TagPO tagDto2Po(TagDTO tagDTO);
```

Is there any elegant way to do so?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should do that. The mapping from `enum` into an `Integer` or `String` using the fields of that `enum` is fairly straightforward and well described at the home page https://mapstruct.org/.

```
@Mapping(target = "tagClass", source = "tagClass.code")
TagPO tagDto2Po(TagDTO tagDTO);
```

```
TagDTO tagDTO = new TagDTO(TagClassEnum.COMMON);   // COMMON(0, "common")
TagPO tagPO = tagMapper.tagDto2Po(tagDTO);         // autowired instance

log.debug(tagPO.getTagClass());                    // prints 0
```

The other way around is a bit harder and would require the `enum` resolution using either a Java [expression](https://mapstruct.org/documentation/stable/reference/html/#expressions) or [`@AfterMapping`](https://mapstruct.org/documentation/stable/reference/html/#passing-context).

Comment: Custom mapping method for mapping from Integer unto the Enum will also do the trick

Comment: I tried to search the official document, due to my poor english I wasn't able to find the solution. Your answer helped a lot and it works, thank you so much!

Comment: I don't find your english worse than mine :) The documentation doesn't give you an explicit solution for your problem but aims you to the way that might work. Here you probably were looking for enums mapping, however, this shall be treated as an ordinary class with getters etc. in this case. Also, as long as you seem new to here, let me suggest you to consider [marking the answer as accepted](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) to let others know you have found the best and working solution to this problem (remember this action is *not* mandatory and is fully up to you).

Comment: Your answer definitely resolved my question, accepted! And yes I'm new here, thank's for the instruction!